# read a '\n' (newline) terminated string using windows via C

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

is it possible to read a random length string , terminated by a newline, using C only and not C++?
ive been trying to find examples but cant seem to find any using windows that uses this. i can accomplish reading data off the serial port but the problem is that these are random in length. there only common factor is that these strings are terminated by newlines. thank you very much

Comment: Yes, it's possibile. Just read it char by char, for example.

Comment: thanks for the reply sir. is there a possibly faster way? or is this the only method that i can use?

Comment: No, a program can't read every character faster than the time it takes to read every character... Why do you think it could be faster than that? Magic? Or skipping some characters and hope they weren't important?

Comment: @Lundin: It is well-established wisdom that reading blocks at a time is faster than reading each character one by one, due to function-call and maybe even context-switching overheads (depending on the API used, of course). If this is not the case for serial I/O, then fair enough, but that certainly wouldn't have been obvious to many people (myself included). Responding with sarcasm is unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: @Marcelo This is indeed not the case for any form of serial I/O, where characters come in one by one. The big bottleneck in this case is the transmission time over RS-232. Even if you are using one of the fastest baudrates the UART can manage, it would still be much slower than the PC.

Comment: @Lundin: *Any* form of serial I/O? What about USB?

Comment: Yes, in any form of low level computer communication, bytes are sent one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not trivially. Call fgets in a loop until you hit a newline, holding onto each buffer you read up to that point.

Comment: You can't use fgets() for the Windows serial port. You will have to use the Windows API functions directly.